# Image Texture Darkens Entire Glass

Tags: node-editor, transparency, uv-image-editor, glass

When I add an image with a transparency layer on the bottle, it darkens the entire bottle and I have no idea what's going on. I followed [this guide](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material) to the word but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

[image]

This is what it looks like with the text image.
[image]

This is what it looks like without the text image.
[image]

Here's a screenshot so y'all can see real quick what the setup's like.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's still residual color information in the alpha area of your png. The better way to fix this is to get rid of the color mix node. Create a seperate shader for your screen-print ink material and wire that and your glass shader node into the mix shader node. Now drive the shader mix with your alpha channel.

[image: Node Setup]

This also allows you to modify the material properties of the ink without the need for a much more complex setup.

[image]

You could also achieve a result with minimal effort using the following node setup:

[image]

But this might not be physically correct, depending on the exact production method for the label, of course.